# d3 stack appears to be working but getting NaN when values are pushed to svg rect

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created this chart initially which is basically what I am trying to recreate except I want the height of the bars to be dynamically populated based on the data in the threshold array:
http://jsfiddle.net/featherita/Lw7KZ/

So, if the values are 1,20,40, it would scale the colored rectangles accordingly.

I'm attempting to use the stack function:

```
var layers = d3.layout.stack()(dataChartData.summaryData.threshold.map(function () {
        return dataChartData.summaryData.threshold.map(function (d) {
            return { x: 0, y: +d, y0: 0 };
            });
    }));
```

This will console log the data (even though my y0 value is currently incorrect), the data is in the right format. However, when I try to take these values and pull them to the rectangle values I get an error: Error: Invalid value for  attribute y="NaN". I'm calling it with "layers":

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(layers, function(d){return d;})
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", 7)
        .attr("x", function (d) { return xScale(d.x); })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return -yScale(d.y0) - yScale(d.y); })
        .attr("height", function (d) { return yScale(d.y); })
        .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d); });
```

Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: are you using jQuery to access dom properties?

Answer (score 0):

Your layers array is not formatted the way you think it is. Right now it is an array of 3 arrays with values you created with the d3.layout.stack function call. With that said and the current format, you can access the values with the following:

```
.attr("y", function (d, i) { return yScale(d[i].y); })
```

Answer (score -1):

is it because your setting the attributes to be Funciton object's instead of Number objects?
 Try adding parenthesis with variables to pass in to the function definitions, like so:

`-    .attr("x", function (d) { return xScale(d.x); }) // Current
+    .attr("x", function (d) { return xScale(d.x); }(d)) // Suggested`